# Windows Phone Parse json data? from Url with user input?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I Followed [this](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page2.htm) to Create Restful Web Services which display JSON as OutPut from the MySQL Data base.

I Successfully Done it, But Here I Have nearly 100 Tables in Database with different name

And I am Getting This kind of Json Data

```
{"WindowsResult":[{"ID":9,"TYPE":"WindowsPhone","TITLE":"XYZ","PRICE":"$0","IMAGE":"Post1.jpg"}],"success":3}
```

this  another result

```
{"SonyResult":[{"ID":3,"TYPE":"SonyXperia","TITLE":"XYZ","PRICE":"$0","IMAGE":"Post2.jpg"}],"success":3}
```

this  another one

```
{"SamsungResult":[{"ID":1,"TYPE":"Samsung","TITLE":"XYZ","PRICE":"$0","IMAGE":"Post3.jpg"}],"success":3}
```

For this I am parsing a JSON data form a url
like localhost/Service1.svc/windows or localhost/Service1.svc/sony like that

Here it should Take with a user input..

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

string Data = txtData.Text;
string ServiceUri = "http://lhost:30576/Service1.svc/"
+ "Data" + "/";
WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
proxy.DownloadStringCompleted +=
new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(proxy_DownloadStringCompleted);
proxy.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(ServiceUri));

}
```

But I am Confused at Here

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
 var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result); 
 foreach (var TYPE in rootObject.SonyResult) 
 { 
 Console.WriteLine(type.TITLE);
 } 
 }
```

what should be at Root object
for some Results I have SamsungResult as Root Object like that.
Please suggest Me Regarding this..

**Update**

when I enter the a url like http://www.google.com/service1.scv/sony

I am getting

```
{"SonyResult":[{"ID":3,"TYPE":"SonyXperia","TITLE":"XYZ","PRICE":"$0","IMAGE":"Post2.jpg"}],"success":3}
```

like that every brand I have one result Not All in one string..

Answer (score 1):

K bro the problem is in your json data

```
{"Mobiles":[
   {"SonyResult":[{"ID":3,"TYPE":"SonyXperia","TITLE":"XYZ","PRICE":"$0","IMAGE":"Post2.jpg"}],"success":3},
   {"WindowsResult":[{"ID":9,"TYPE":"WindowsPhone","TITLE":"XYZ","PRICE":"$0","IMAGE":"Post1.jpg"}],"success":3}
]}
```

Since you hadn't specified a Root object name for our tables so json was using your table names as root objects.

Its C# class will be

```
public class SonyResult
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string TYPE { get; set; }
public string TITLE { get; set; }
public string PRICE { get; set; }
public string IMAGE { get; set; }
}
public class WindowsResult
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string TYPE { get; set; }
public string TITLE { get; set; }
public string PRICE { get; set; }
public string IMAGE { get; set; }
}
public class Mobile
{
public List<SonyResult> SonyResult { get; set; }
public int success { get; set; }
public List<WindowsResult> WindowsResult { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
public List<Mobile> Mobiles { get; set; }
}
```

Hope that solved your problem.
**Update**
For ur received query the C# class is going to be

```
public class SonyResult 
{public int ID { get; set; }
 public string TYPE { get; set; }
 public string TITLE { get; set; }
 public string PRICE { get; set; }
 public string IMAGE { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
 public List<SonyResult> SonyResult { get; set; }
 public int success { get; set; }
}
```

Now since for each different models you are getting different queries where each are an array of its own with no common object name. So for each different model the root object class will differ.
I havent tried it as I dont have access to your code but try if this format works(Since I havent tried this so I have my doubts if this will work or not).

```
public class SonyResult
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string TYPE { get; set; }
public string TITLE { get; set; }
public string PRICE { get; set; }
public string IMAGE { get; set; }
}
public class WindowsResult
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string TYPE { get; set; }
public string TITLE { get; set; }
public string PRICE { get; set; }
public string IMAGE { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
public List<SonyResult> SonyResult { get; set; }
public int success { get; set; }
public List<WindowsResult> WindowsResult { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thaks @jerin Sir But Here my Problem is that Instead of Mobiles I have SonyResult like that I mean It start with one string not all phones list in one string... Thanks for the replay But Please try to help me,,,, please check with my update question...

Comment: I have created a chatroom where I can help you if u have more problem
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55112/jerin-and-dont-be-negative-conversation

Comment: Thanks @Jerin Sir, But My Qestion is that Root Object may be any thing like SonyResult like you have taken Mobile it should automatically replace the data .. with SonyResult ,samusng result like that for each type..

Comment: For that did you try adding SonyResult and WindowResult in the root object? Does it work. were u able to deserialize?

Comment: sir it should be one result at a time not all at a time.. if i search sony it should display sony,if i search iphone it should show that specific one.....

Comment: Then I would suggest you to check out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648193/how-to-deserialize-a-dynamically-named-root-node-with-json-net
Since my answer now is going to be almost similar to this